# Why does SHIFT+V (VISUAL LINE) not multi-line insert the way CTRL+V (VISUAL BLOCK) does?

Tags: vim

I'm just curious, why do I have to use *visual block* selection to insert into multiple lines instead of *visual line*?

What is the difference behind the scenes that causes this difference?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How would you expect it to work?  Where would the text be inserted and why?

Comment: My thinking was that since `I` inserts at the beginning of a line, when multiple lines were selected it would apply that command to every line. I understood why _visual block_ works like that (thanks to /u/Kent), but not why _visual line_ does not offer `I` or `A` functionality by default as /u/Ingo_Karkat mentioned. Thanks to his explanation I think I get it now though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *blockwise* selection is the more generic one, i.e. it allows insertion of multiple lines at any place. Of course, you can think of linewise (and even characterwise) selections as degenerate cases of that, but it would be less universal (linewise would only allow insertion at column 1 or the end of lines), and therefore isn't offered by default; i.e. `I` and `A` are only available in blockwise visual mode. However, it's trivial to add these to the other selection modes, too:

```
" {Visual}I, {Visual}A  Make I/A available in characterwise visual and linewise
"                       visual mode.
" Source: kana, http://whileimautomaton.net/
function! s:ForceBlockwiseVisualExpr()
    if mode() ==# 'v'
        return "\<Esc>g`<\<C-v>g`>"
    elseif mode() ==# 'V'
        return "\<Esc>g`<^\<C-v>g`>$"
    else
        return ''
    endif
endfunction
xnoremap <expr> <silent> I <SID>ForceBlockwiseVisualExpr() . 'I'
xnoremap <expr> <silent> A <SID>ForceBlockwiseVisualExpr() . 'A'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can understand it as "line-mode" and "column-mode". You want to add something on same **column** of multiple lines, you use "ctrl-v" (column mode).